# Can't send javascript object array to new page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a javascript array of objects that I am trying to send to my new view. I don't want to use AJAX - this is a new page altogether. I can't seem to figure out how to send the array to my controller action.

I have an action that returns an `UploadFile` object to my view, which is added to an array in javascript. When the user tries to continue to "review" the results, I'm sending that array of objects to the new page.

```
public ActionResult Review(List<UploadFile> model)
{
    return View();
}
```

I still tried using AJAX but I encountered two problems: 1) I want a new page, I don't want it to stay on the same page, 2) The model is still null.

```
$('.js_btn-review').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Document/Review',
        data: documents,
        type: 'GET'
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how to do this - I know I've done it before, but I can't remember how I did it. I even tried setting an element and serializing:

```
$('.js_btn-review').click(function () {
    $("#documents").val(documents);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Document/Review',
        data: $("#documents").serialize(),
        type: 'GET'
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you need to process or store the list on the server?

Comment: did you try the parameter an array?  UploadFile[]

Comment: if that doesnt work wrap your data object like this --> JSON.stringify(documents).  Also the Parameter name must be the same as the json object name

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't state the structure of the js variable documents I am assuming it is just an array of UploadFiles. Something along the lines of:

```
        var documents = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var d = {
                id: i,
                title: i.toString()
            };
            documents.push(d);
        }
```

Which you then taking and sending via ajax. This will not work as documents do not have a container so the URL for the GET will look something like /Document/Review?undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&

By changing it to

```
        var data = {
            model: documents
        };
        $('.js_btn-review').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Review',
                data: data,
                type: 'GET'
            });
        });
```

The models should be populated.

As for the view changing you will need to do something other than .ajax as just goes and gets the response. it doesn't change pages.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name should be the same as the name of the data being sent, so if the data object is called documents, your parameter in the controller should have the same name as follows.

```
public ActionResult Review(List<UploadFile> documents)
{
    return View();
}
```

the Javascript for that

```
$('.js_btn-review').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Document/Review',
        data: JSON.stringify( documents ),
        type: 'Post'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without AJAX**
It's just like the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) so you POST a form.

```
@{
    List<UploadFile> list = new List<UploadFile> { ... };
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Review", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => list[i]);
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Review" />
}
```

**Controller Actions**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(List<UploadFile> list)
{
    TempData["Review_list"] = list;
    return RedirectToAction("Review");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Review()
{
    var list = TempData["Review_list] as List<UploadFile>;
    return View(list);
}
```

**If you don't need to process the list on the server**

Don't bother with passing back and keep the list in javascript:

1. Store it in [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) like `sessionStorage` as JSON
2. Do a regular GET to navigate to your new page (e.g. `<a href="../review">Review</a>`)
3. Retrieve the list from `sessionStorage` and build the html